# Can I access filesystem of my iPhone using Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode

Is there any way to get access directly to the filesystem of iPhone connected to my Mac using Xcode?

Please keep in mind that the question is NOT about accessing filesystem from application (which is not possible outside of the application's sandbox) but about accessing it from Xcode.

The actual problem is with data on my iPhone which was somehow corrupted while developing several applications. The problem becomes even more stupid because of corrupted data being copied while doing backups and restoring system from it.

Maybe there are other ways to access device's filesystem without jailbreak?

Comment: You can access your "own" files from within the Xcode organizer.

Answer (score 9):

Connect your iPhone and fire up Xcode. Open the Organizer and select your device, and then 'Applications'. You will now see a list of applications that should look familiar to you ;)

Select an app and click 'Download' at the bottom of Organizer.

If you wait long enough, you can even see the files down in 'Data files in sandbox'.